# R Quandl - Loop

Tags: r, function, loops, quandl

EDIT: Hi everyone, I want to download all Gold individual contracts from Quandl. The contracts are from 1975 to 2016 with the month codes: G(February) J(April) M(June) Q(August) V(October) Z(December). At the bottom of the link appears all of them [CME Gold Futures](https://www.quandl.com/collections/futures/cme-gold-futures).
So if you click on one individual contract, let's say the oldest one, is February 1975 and the syntax to download it in R is:

```
require(Quandl)
Quandl("CME/GCG1975")
```

General Syntax:

```
Quandl(":database_code/:dataset_code", type = ":return_format")

"database_code" : CME (Chicago Mercantile Exchange)
"dataset_code" : INSTRUMENT:MONTH:YEAR (example: GC:G:1975 without colon)
```

Parameters:

```
The parameter order can take the following values:

   "asc" : return data in ascending order
   "desc" : return data in descending order

The parameter type can take the following values:

   "raw" : returns a data frame
   "zoo" : returns a zoo object
   "ts" : returns a time-series object
   "xts" : returns an extensible time-series object
   "timeSeries" : returns a financial time-series object

When type is omitted, a data frame is returned.
```

Now, I do what I want for the last 2 contracts, February and April 1975:

```
require(Quandl)

pre_contract <- Quandl("CME/GCG1975",order = "asc", type="raw") #download previous or February 1975 and post contract starting from February 1975, then April 1975, June 1975...
post_contract <- Quandl("CME/GCJ1975",order = "asc", type="raw") #download post contract or April 1975

pre_contract$Last = pre_contract$Change = NULL #delete column Last and Change
post_contract$Last = post_contract$Change = NULL #delete column Last and Change

colnames(pre_contract) # output: [1] "Date" [2] "Open" [3] "High" [4] "Low" [5] "Settle" [6] "Volume" [7] "Prev. Day Open Interest"

row_pre = nrow(pre_contract)-5 # this is the 6th last row
pre_contract[row_pre,"Date"] #output: "1975-02-18" this is the 6th last date, col 33 from the total columns 38, not necessary

row_post = which(post_contract$Date == pre_contract[nrow(pre_contract)-5,"Date"]) #output:33 says which row in post_contract is "Date" 1975-02-18
post_contract[row_post,"Date"] #output:"1975-02-18"  my visual confirmation, not necessary

row_pre <- row_pre - 1 # I don't want to add 2 times the same date (1975-02-18), and I want the row of the April 1975
contract_union <- rbind(pre_contract[1:row_pre,],post_contract[row_post:nrow(post_contract),]) #I paste both contracts in same data.frame, the division-date is 1975-02-18 where I use the row of the April 1975
```

Next step, is to do the same but with April 1975 as pre_contract and June 1975 as post_contract, until December 2016 that is the actual contract, and finally `contract_union` have all contracts in ascending order.
For this project I don't know which instruments/commands to use. I think that in the syntax of `Quandl` `CME/GC` could be fixed and put `monthcode` and `year` as variable with limits, limits of monthcode are the letters of months `G J M Q V Z` and limits of years are `1975:2016`.

```
require(xlsx)
write.xlsx(contract_union,"/gold-data.xlsx")
```

I don't need a final-solution, if you can help me/guidance me in any part is fine. I'm open to any suggestions/questions. And I'm open to learn anything useful for this project.

Thanks,
RTA

Comment: Questions that occur to me: Do you realize that assigning to `x` twice will overwrite the first value? Is there some difficulty getting `Quandl` tp process a value constructed from `paste0`? What is the structure of the object that `Quandl` delivers? What does it mean to say "compute the third contract with the second"? What are (xy1,xy2)?

Comment: Thanks @42- for your questions, I have edited the question and answered yours, I don't know what to do with `paste0` even I don't know if it's necessary. Hope you understand now my question

Comment: I thought you wanted to prepend ""CME/GC" to  all combinations of GJMQV crossed with your years. Uising expand.grid and then `apply` along rows using `paste0` would seem the most economical method to generate your requests. I don't generally find code without a natural language explanation very useful in setting up a problem. I also would have guessed that you wanted to assign the result of `Quandl("CME/GCG1975")` to an R name. Then if you wanted to loop through the names you might be in a position to grab two at a time in sequence for whatever your code does.

Comment: Yes,now the code is clearer.Thanks for your sincerity about -natural language explanation-. I understand about you say me, to do `qt = expand.grid.df(data.frame(Year=1975:2016), data.frame(Month="G","J","M","Q","V"))`Now I've got a `data.frame` with "integer" in column 1 and the next 5 columns as "factor".Now I must do what your last sentence says -be in a position to grab two at a time in sequence- but I don't understand it. I have divided this question in other post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40953151/loop-r-with-quandl-as-optional] so there is more information. Thanks for your time